# Accessing only certain members of a struct and not all of them

Tags: c, struct

I currently have a struct with 8 members that need to be used.

```
typedef struct Foo_s
{
    uint8_t a;
    uint8_t b;
    uint8_t c;
    uint16_t d;
    uint8_t e;
    uint16_t f;
    uint32_t g;
    uint32_t h;
} Foo_s;
```

There are two use cases with this struct, read and write, where read uses all 8 members and write only uses the first 5 (a-e).

Currently, I have broken this into two separate structs, one for read (with 8 members) and one for write (with 5 members) however it was suggested that I could use one struct for both, and when passing the members needed for 'write' functionality to only access the first 5 members.

```
if(x == y){ 
    BarRead(&readStruct);
} else {
    BarWrite(&writeStruct);
}
```

Rather than passing `readStruct` and `writeStruct`, I want to use just one struct, `genericStruct`. For the if condition I can just pass `&genericStruct` and that will work fine, however, I don't know what to pass in the else condition.

I just want to pass the first 5 members of the struct in the else condition. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Sidenote: *"however it was suggested that I could use one struct for both"* You could, but *should* you? It depends on what these members actually represent. If they form a distinct entity, maybe you should separate them to third struct, and include that as a member to other structs when necessary.

Comment: These structs currently represent responses from the client. If the client is reading a file from the server, they receive a response based on the read struct. If the client is writing a file to the server, they receive a response based on the write struct. It was my suggestion to use two structs however the team's tech lead suggested using one.

Comment: So structs are used for serialization? You have encourtered one reason (out of many) why that is bad idea: they are incapable of representing variable length information. I would use structs only as in memory representation of data, and use dedicated funtions for converting data to/from transmittable bytes manually. That being said, I think your original approach of having different types is better than single type, because they represent distinct things.

Comment: Note that the three `uint8_t` followed by a `uint16_t` virtually guarantees padding within the structure. Reverse the order of `d` and `e` to avoid padding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could declare the struct itself as anything, if you hide it behind private encapsulation. This will be one option: let access to the struct be done only through setters/getters.

Suppose you define two structs like this:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  a;
  uint8_t  b;
  uint8_t  c;
  uint16_t d;
  uint8_t  e;
} foo_write_t;

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  a;
  uint8_t  b;
  uint8_t  c;
  uint16_t d;
  uint8_t  e;
  uint16_t f;
  uint32_t g;
  uint32_t h;
} foo_read_t;
```

You can then make a new ADT which contains both, with overlapping elements. A `union`, such as this:

```
union foo_t
{
  foo_write_t write;
  foo_read_t  read;
  struct                 // C11 anonymous struct
  {
    uint8_t  a;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint8_t  c;
    uint16_t d;
    uint8_t  e;
    uint16_t f;
    uint32_t g;
    uint32_t h;
  };
};
```

The above now has 3 different ways to access the same memory. `foo.a`, `foo.write.a` or `foo.read.a`. However, `foo.write` lacks f,g,h. If we add private encapsulation, we can also block direct access to `foo.a`.

In C, private encapsulation is done through *opaque type*, the header "foo.h" becomes something like this:

```
// foo.h
typedef union foo_t foo_t;

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  a;
  uint8_t  b;
  uint8_t  c;
  uint16_t d;
  uint8_t  e;
} foo_write_t;

typedef struct
{
  uint8_t  a;
  uint8_t  b;
  uint8_t  c;
  uint16_t d;
  uint8_t  e;
  uint16_t f;
  uint32_t g;
  uint32_t h;
} foo_read_t;


foo_t* foo_init(
  uint8_t  a,
  uint8_t  b,
  uint8_t  c,
  uint16_t d,
  uint8_t  e,
  uint16_t f,
  uint32_t g,
  uint32_t h);

void foo_delete (foo_t* foo);
```

and the corresponding c file:

```
// foo.c
#include "foo.h"

union foo_t
{
  foo_write_t write;
  foo_read_t  read;
  struct 
  {
    uint8_t  a;
    uint8_t  b;
    uint8_t  c;
    uint16_t d;
    uint8_t  e;
    uint16_t f;
    uint32_t g;
    uint32_t h;
  };
};

foo_t* foo_init(
  uint8_t  a,
  uint8_t  b,
  uint8_t  c,
  uint16_t d,
  uint8_t  e,
  uint16_t f,
  uint32_t g,
  uint32_t h)
{
  foo_t* foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
  if(foo==NULL)
  {
    return NULL;
  }

  foo->a = a;
  foo->b = b;
  foo->c = c;
  foo->d = d;
  foo->e = e;
  foo->f = f;
  foo->g = g;
  foo->h = h;

  return foo;
}

void foo_delete (foo_t* foo)
{
  free(foo);
}
```

Then you can provide access through setters/getters. Either by only allowing hard copies, something like this:

```
void foo_write (foo_t* foo, const foo_write_t* foo_w)
{
  memcpy(foo, foo_w, sizeof foo->write);
}

void foo_read (const foo_t* foo, foo_read_t* foo_r)
{
  memcpy(foo_r, foo, sizeof foo->read);
}
```

or by allowing the caller to write directly into the ADT by exposing and returing the address to the relevant part of the struct:

```
foo_write_t* foo_get_write (foo_t* foo)
{
  return &foo->write;
}

const foo_read_t* foo_get_read (foo_t* foo)
{
  return &foo->read;
}
```

Comment: That's perfect, thank you for the detailed response!